# Maven compiling with different JDK versions

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx, maven-compiler-plugin

My application is split between users on Java 1.6u45 and Java 1.8.  Our problem is that we cannot specify the project system library and have two different compiler settings for the code at the same time.

Project Structure:

```
Project >
    > src/main/java/com/us/javafx/... (Java 8 code)
    > src/main/java/com/us/... (Java 6 code)
    > src/main/resources/...
```

Our POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.us</groupId>
   <artifactId>PROJECT</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <name>PROJECT</name>
   <description>DESCR</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Copy all dependencies to jars directory -->
          <plugin> 
              <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId> 
                  <executions> 
                      <execution> 
                          <phase>package</phase> 
                          <goals> 
                              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal> 
                          </goals> 
                          <configuration> 
                              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jars</outputDirectory> 
                          </configuration> 
                      </execution> 
                  </executions> 
          </plugin>


            <!-- Maven Compiler -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>  
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Necessary to avoid setting JRE on Maven project update! -->
                    <!-- SEE PHOTO FOR WHY THIS IS HERE -->
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>            
                <executions>

                    <!-- Compile Java 6 directory -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>java6</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>com/us/javafx/**/*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <!-- Non working attempt to set compiler version -->
                            <source>1.6</source>
                            <target>1.6</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <!-- Compile Java 8 directory -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>java8</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>com/us/javafx/**/*</include>
                            </includes>
                            <!-- Non working attempt to set compiler version -->
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Create JAR in jars folder -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jars</outputDirectory> 
                </configuration>
              </plugin>

        </plugins>
</build>
```

If we tell the Maven compiler plugin to use Java 1.8, Java 1.6 users get the unsupported major minor version error.  Or we tell the Maven compiler plugin to use Java 1.6 but our Java 8 code will complain about errors when performing Right Click Project > Maven > Update Project... (which causes the screen shot below):

[image]

Is there a way we can achieve both:

1) Compile Java 6 and 8 code with their respective compilers

2) Choose Java 8 as our project's JRE System Library

Comment: You can only make two separate maven projects from it make the appropriate configuration for maven-compiler in the project and combine them via a parent (this is called multi module build). Apart from that within any IDE that does not work as well..only separated projects this will work.

Comment: You could try using profiles and run the build twice, once for each profile. Maybe not the most elegant. Modern CI such as Go should allow you to run the builds in parallel assuming enough nodes available.

Comment: I appreciate the help!

For now am I just adding in the JVM argument when I do a production build:

mvn clean package -Dmaven.compiler.source=1.6 -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.6

and keeping my POM.xml in the configuration that suits my IDE

Comment: As khmarbaise commented, the only way to go is to split the 1.6 and 1.8 codebases each into its own separate project.

Answer (score 2):

I recently learned about toolchains.xml. Maven has it even documented and supports it from 2.0.9! See [toolchains documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html)

So I added a toolchain.xml file to my ~/.m2/ folder with following content:

```xml
<toolchains xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/TOOLCHAINS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/TOOLCHAINS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/toolchains-1.1.0.xsd">
 <!-- JDK toolchains -->
 <toolchain>
   <type>jdk</type>
   <provides>
     <version>1.8</version>
     <vendor>sun</vendor>
   </provides>
   <configuration>
     <jdkHome>/opt/java8</jdkHome>
   </configuration>
 </toolchain>
 <toolchain>
   <type>jdk</type>
   <provides>
     <version>1.7</version>
     <vendor>sun</vendor>
   </provides>
   <configuration>
     <jdkHome>/opt/java7</jdkHome>
   </configuration>
 </toolchain>
</toolchains>
```

It allows you to define what different JDKs Maven can use to build the project irrespective of the JDK Maven runs with. Sort of like when you define JDK on project level in IDE. I used it when I needed to build another project with Java 7 while having Java 8 as a default.

I guess this can solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maven profiles is the simplest and most effective one.
You can elect and run them from your IDE too.
You design a profile for each different JDK you need. You put in each different JDK profile :

- properties like source code target
- dependencies that are specialised for that profile.

```
Project
    +properties
    +dependencies
    +Profiles
        Profile JDK8
            +jdk8-properties
                jdk.version
                maven.compiler.source
                maven.compiler.target   
            +jdk8-dependencies
        Profile JDK11
            +jdk11-properties
                jdk.version
                maven.compiler.source
                maven.compiler.target   
            +jdk11-dependencies
```

[Picture of maven profiles tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56urK.png)

And an example

```
<project>
    <name>x</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.210</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <!-- different Java versions -->
        <profile>
            <id>jdk8</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
                <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
                <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core-jakarta</artifactId>
                    <version>5.6.10.Final</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- needed if jakarta is used -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>42.2.25</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>jdk11</id>
            <properties>
                <jdk.version>11</jdk.version>
                <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
                <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                    <version>6.1.2.Final</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>42.4.2</version>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <properties>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <junit-version>4.13.2</junit-version>
    </properties>
</project>
```